# Service Fabric Explorer not accessible

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

It gives `This site can’t be reached fabric-service-url.com unexpectedly closed the connection.` error.

I am using Mac computer.

Accessing the url from Chrome.

The certificate comes from the *.pfx translated *.pem.

Comment: Really not enough information to go on. Also, not a developr question so you will likely get downvoted on Stack Overflow just an FYI. Anyways, I would check the docs on connecting to your cluster https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster There was likely a step missed either during the deployment or importing the cluster locally. You could also try form a windows machine to see if the issue is the same that way you can determine if it is a MAC issue or not

Comment: Any update? Were you able to get it resolved?

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT This problem has been temporarily solved by following this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2019/02/07/known-issue-for-service-fabric-linux-clusters/ .
But it feel like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this by deleting the previously installed Service Fabric certificate from the certificate store on my laptop, rebooting, installing the certificate again (on Windows 10: double click the `.pfx` file, next, next, finish) and rebooting again.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail, please? Which Service Fabric certificate did you delete and from where? Where is the .pfx file that you double-clicked?